# Strapi Image Upload

Tags: next.js, strapi

I have an issue with the /upload route in my application.

I can get it working and uploading, my issue is that /upload route is open and any authenticated can use it, therefore can upload at will and also will be able to post to entires that do they have control over.  Can I set up for example an isAuthenticatedUser policy for the route which checks it the correct authenticated user?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState();

    const uploadImage = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("files", files[0]);

      axios
        .post("http://localhost:1337/api/upload/", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          const imageId = response.data[0].id;

          axios
            .post("http://localhost:1337/api/images", { image: imageId })
            .then((response) => {
              //handle success
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              //handle error
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          //handle error
        });
    };







<form onSubmit={uploadImage}>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setFiles(e.target.files)} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).